# Putting email + md5-hashed password into db using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, md5

A website i'm building had a small admin-panel. So the site has a login page, but no registration page because there is only 1 email+password needed to login for 1 account. So i wanted to insert the credentials for this 1 account through sql. The password needs to be md5-hashed. This is the sql code i wrote, but i get an error:

```
insert into tblmember (memberEmail, memberWachtwoord) 
        values (
        '".mysqli_real_escape_string('exampleemail')."',
        '".hash('md5', mysqli_real_escape_string('examplepassword'))."'
        );
```

exampleemail and examplepassword are just text, no variables.
This is the error i get:

```
error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'exampleemail')."', '".hash('md5'('examplepassword'))."' )' at line 3
```

Comment: You have PHP in your SQL code. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: If you can, change the password hash. MD5 is no longer considered secure. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23116/md5-collision-attacks-are-they-relevant-in-password-hashing for a relatively balanced question & answers on why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you strip the PHP code, you'll get this:

`insert into tblmember (memberEmail, memberWachtwoord) 
        values ('exampleemail', md5('examplepassword'));`

Comment: It's been ages i worked with sql directly without php... Well, at least i remember how sql works again :) Thanks!